# How to break up a very large excel file

Tags: excel

I have a very large excel file (7gb) from an external source.  It is too large to open.  It only contains one worksheet and about 1 million rows and 100 columns.  Normally, I could use PowerPivot to do data analysis with the file as a data source.

However, I have to go in to the spreadsheet and add one column for longitude, one column for latitude, and then an equation to convert the address to a latitude and longitude.  Therefore, I somehow have to break apart this excel file into many smaller excel files (i.e. 20 files of 50,000 rows each).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for Python Pandas module: https://pandas.pydata.org It can easily read Excel files, manipulate the data, and write it out to another file.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem aswell. My solution was to go to splitmyexcelfile.com and from there you can choose how much files you want and how much rows you want in each file. I hope this solves your problem for the `I somehow have to break apart this excel file into many smaller excel files` part of your question.

Comment: I would be extremely hesitant to send my data to a website. Be cautious with this solution.

Comment: Yep, this may be very sketchy so I would advise caution if you're using important data.